# Number of possible combinations of fork

Tags: c, math, fork, combinatorics

```
int main(void) { 
  int id = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    if(fork() == 0) {
      id = i;
    } else {
      printf("Process %d created child %d\n", id, i);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the code above, multiple ordering of the output (printf statements) can be generated based on how the operating system schedules processes for execution. How many different orderings are possible? You may assume that all fork and printf calls succeed.

I'm trying to help my students understand how to approach this problem, however I got a nice 0 on this question when I wrote the exam. I was hoping someone could explain how to go about it?

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: Since output can be interleaved, the possible number of combinations is massive.

Comment: This is the c language. And yes I know it is massive. This is a question on an exam asking for an exact answer not a “it’s big”

Comment: Please post your answer, and the reasoning you used to calculate it. Then we can help you understand where you went wrong. But isn't this the job of the professor or teaching assistant? You're paying them to teach you this stuff.

Comment: Oops, you *are* the teacher!

Comment: At least print the process id of the current process:`printf("Process %d[%d] created child %d\n", getpid(),id, i);` (and the  childs pid,too)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked out all the combinations at the end, but this should get you going.

You start with a parent process. It will call `fork()` 3 times, and print

```
Process 0 created child 1
Process 0 created child 2
Process 0 created child 3
```

After its first fork there's one child process with `id = 1`. This process will continue the loop, so it will print

```
Process 1 created child 2
Process 1 created child 3
```

The parent process will then fork a child with `id = 2`. This process will also continue its loop, so it will print

```
Process 2 created child 3
```

That's all the first generation children. But child 1 also forks its own child 2, which will print

```
Process 2 created child 3
```

All the processes that are forked when `i = 3` exit the loop immediately. They don't fork any more children, or print anything, so they can be ignored.

Each process prints its own messages in order, but they can be interspersed in any order between the processes. The one constraint is that a a child can't print anything before its parent prints the message saying that it created an earlier child, because the message is printed before the iteration that creates the child (I'm assuming output is line buffered). But it *can* print its own messages before the message that says it was created!

So the first two messages can be either:

```
Process 0 created child 1
Process 1 created child 2
```

or

```
Process 1 created child 2
Process 0 created child 1
```