# How to know the output in the code with fork()?

Tags: c, unix, fork

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main ()
{
    W(A);
    int child=fork();
    W(B);
    if (child)
      wait(NULL);
    W(C);
}
```

I think that ABBCC will be one of the outputs, but also one more of the next ones: ACCBB, ABB, ABCBC, ABCAA should be correct. W means write and W(A), W(B), W(C) mean to write A, B, C. Please help.

Comment: It all hinges on the missing information — what the macro `W` is and then, maybe, what the values `A`, `B`, `C` represent.  This isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]) — it is missing key information, so it is sub-minimal and incomplete and hence unverifiable.   (Saying "`W` means write, …" isn't helpful; we need to _see_ how `W` is defined.  There are all sorts of interesting things that can be done wrong.)

Comment: It also isn't entirely clear what you're asking.  Are you asking what the output will be, or can be?

Comment: As written, the code does not compile.  You've omitted the definition of W.  You get different results depending on whether you have `#define W(x) write(0, #x, 1)` or `#define W(x) putchar(#x[0])` or `#define W(x) fwrite(#x, 1, 1, stdout)`, etc.  Which of the many available options have you chosen, or been given?

Comment: The function: `fork()` returns three(3) kinds of values: 1) >0 means in the parent  2) ==0 means in the child 3) <0 means an error occurred, not child created, still in parent The posted pseudo code 1) doesn't compile 2) fails to check for a failure of `fork()`, etc.  So the actual output sequence is in determinant.  Also, you could have ran some real code in minutes rather than waiting for us to figure out what you think the code was doing, (as against what some real code written in this manner would do.)  In the future, please read/understand the MAN page for the functions you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACCBB` is not possible.

I'll add a subscript <sub>p</sub> for letters printed by the parent, <sub>c</sub> for the child.

The parent process prints A<sub>p</sub>B<sub>p</sub>C<sub>p</sub> in that order, and the child process prints B<sub>c</sub>C<sub>c</sub> in that order.

A<sub>p</sub> will be printed first, because it's printed before anything is forked. The parent waits for the child to exit before printing C<sub>p</sub>, so this has to come last. So this means the first and last characters are `A` and `C`.

In between this, there are no constraints on the order of execution between the two processes. So the following are possible:

B<sub>p</sub>B<sub>c</sub>C<sub>c</sub>
B<sub>c</sub>B<sub>p</sub>C<sub>c</sub>
B<sub>c</sub>C<sub>c</sub>B<sub>p</sub>

The first two look the same in output, since we can't tell the difference between B<sub>p</sub> and B<sub>c</sub>

So the possible results are:

```
ABBCC
ABCBC
```

This all assumes that there's no buffering that might delay the output. I.e. this is just an exercise to examine the order that statements can be executed in concurrent processes, not really about I/O.

Comment: If the output mechanism used standard I/O (`#define W(x) putchar(#x[0])`), then you would get two A's printed unless buffering was turned off (e.g. `setbuf(stdout, NULL)`).  That is probably not what's being used, but it is annoying that the OP refuses to provide an MCVE.  (Otherwise, nice presentation of the analysis.)

Comment: As I said in my last paragraph, I think that's just a placeholder that could be any statement, as this is an exercise to understand how multiple processes work, not I/O.

Comment: Yes it is about how multiple processes work and only what I wrote is given. Two of the given answers is said that are correct and they are ABBCC and ABCBC. So Barmar thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to see a more complicated challenge that I couldn't figure out the full result, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622057/number-of-possible-combinations-of-fork/55622726#55622726